# Unity2D: Reduce Y of square during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I struggle to reduce the Y-Scale of a square, while shifting the Y-position downwards,
so the square stays in place.
It should be like a healthbar for remaining oxygen, but in a gameobject not on a canvas.

I reduce the scale of the square over time with this code:

```
float remainingAir = 100f;

void Start()
{
defaultY = oxygenOverlay.transform.localScale.y;
yPercent = defaultY / air;
}
float reduceFactor = newY * air;    

void AdjustOxygenBar()
{

oxygenOverlay.transform.localScale =  new Vector3(oxygenOverlay.transform.localScale.x, yPercent * remainingAir ,oxygenOverlay.transform.localScale.z);
}
```

The scale reduced from both sides of the square. How do I move the square downward each frame, so the square will only reduce from top to bottom?

Thanks on advance

Comment: You need to change how the object is anchored; it is in the center by default if I remember correctly.

Comment: @rotgers remembers correctly ^^ so either you mesh needs to be offset by `y += height / 2` or you need to nest your model object under a parent object, apply this offset in Y to your child object relative to the new parent  and then rather scale the parent object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have tried this and it works to scale only on Y axis, however it will shrink towards the center of the object so yes you have to move it down to make the effect thats a bar thats being unfilled

```
    void Awake ()
    {
        percent = 100;        
    }
    
    
    void Update ()
    {
        percent -= 0.1f;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x,transform.localScale.y*percent/100,transform.localScale.z);
    }
```